# Method to encapsulate reusable view sections (i.e. tiles, portlets) with arbitrary content?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm still getting my feet wet with MVC and working on a site that uses a lot of "tiles" (you know, the usual "rectangular section with standardized header and some content" pattern) for the visual display. There's nothing fancy, just a way to put content into boxes for ease of layout and navigation. Currently the "tiles" (my term) are built like this:

```
<div class="tile">
    <div class="tile-header">
        <h2>Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tile-body">
        (arbitrary content)
    </div>
</div>
```

*Note: "arbitrary content" means any content, either static or dynamic, so not necessarily something I can plug into a variable and pass into a helper, I need a bit more flexibility.*

My question is, what is the optimal method to use to encapsulate this pattern and make it easier/more expressive to call from code? I know about partial views, but how would I pass arbitrary body content to a partial view? (This may simply be my limited knowledge of MVC showing)

I tried building Razor helpers like this:

```
@Tile.Begin("Title")
    (arbitrary content)
@Tile.End()
```

But Razor chokes because I can't include the "tile-body" closing div. (If I do then I have to pass the body content as a string variable, and that isn't always feasible)

I could see something like this:

```
@using (Tile.Begin("Title")) {
    (arbitrary content)
}
```

This seems the most elegant to me, though not as easy to scan as the @Tile.Begin() and @Tile.End() calls. From what I understand I would have to create a class and implement IDisposable, but when I tried returning a string of raw HTML tags from a helper class it simply wrote the encoded tag syntax to the screen, so I assume I'd run into the same issue here?

Thanks for any advice. :)

Comment: Are you talking about fixed (static) tiles? or Dynamic (data driven) tiles?  That is, do you want to define the tiles in your .cshtml files, or do you want to build the times in code?

Comment: Actually both. For example, right now I'm building a screen that is essentially a collection of lists, each list iterating a collection of models. These models are attached to the view model that is passed to the view. So in essence the view is taking each model collection and building a tile for it, with links. This one I can wrap up in a helper, sure. But another page has the same tile format with static content, which I can't just pass in as a variable. I'd rather have _one_ central place to maintain the layout for the tiles since that is DRY, but I just don't know how to get there. Thanks.

Comment: Actually no I can't easily wrap this one into a helper either, because not all models have the same method call. I guess I can just overload ToString() on each model, unless that is an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would suggest using Display/EditorTemplates for dynamic tile generation.  You could even combine them with an html helper (not razor helper).

Your issue with the custom html helper was that you were not doing it correctly.  You have to use the HtmlHelper object.  The correct way is something like this:

```
public static class TileExtension {

    public static TileHelper Tile(this HtmlHelper helper, string title) {
        helper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(
            "<div class=\"tile\"><div class=\"tile-header\"><h2>" + title + "</h2></div>"
            + "<div class=\"tile-body\">"
        );
        return new TileHelper(helper);
    }

    private class TileHelper : IDisposable {
        private HtmlHelper _helper;
        public TileHelper(HtmlHelper helper) { _helper = helper; }
        public void Dispose() {
           _helper.ViewContext.Writer.Write("</div></div>");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would use this like `@using(Html.Tile("Title")) { // your content }`

Make sure you pay close attention to the static keywords, and the use of the `this` keyword in the parameter.  These are necessary to make the extension work.

Also, you should add the namespace you created this class in to the pages/namespaces element of web.config:

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="My.Name.Space" />
    </namespaces>
<pages>
```

Comment: OK thanks, I wasn't aware of the ViewContext.Writer object, that will come in handy. Unfortunately when I try to implement the above code there is no Tile() method showing for the Html helper object. What I did is create a Tile.cs file in the App_Code folder (where my cshtml helper files are). I did include the first helper extension parameter, and did a full rebuild, and even did a `@using ProjectName.App_Code;` at the top of the view but it still didn't pick it up. So I must be missing something simple, but where? Also, how would you implement DisplayTemplates as you mentioned? Thanks again.

Comment: @Dave - sorry, not sure what I was thinking before.  Try the updated version.

Comment: OK sorry I never could get that to work. I even added a namespace reference to the razors element in the web.config file. If I refence the namespace in my view (@using Project.Views.Helpers) then I can see the class, but it never shows up as @Html.Tile() at all. But since I can at least get a static class I'll go with the Tile.Begin()... Tile.End() syntax. I'm sure there is some MVC mojo I'm missing but I'll figure it out later. Marked as answered since it points me in the right direction. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dave - You have to make sure you have static on both the class and Tile methods, as well as the `this` before HtmlHelper in the `Tile()` methods parameters.  And then you need to add the namespace of your helper to the Web.config pages/namespaces element `<add namespace="Your.Name.Space" />`

Comment: Doh! I dropped the `this` keyword when I built mine -- that did it! Thanks! Now I can do the same for the CSS grid. Seriously, thanks for taking the time, I appreciate it.